# DC-DC Converter output: 6.21 V instead of 5.5 V

Tags: dc-dc-converter, schematics

I am using a [MGDSK10H5,5](https://gaia-converter.com/docs/ds/DSK/MGDk10.pdf) in my design for generating 5.5 V. The MGDSK10H5,5 is an isolated DC-DC converter, but I am using it as a non-isolated DC-DC converter; I have shorted input and output grounds of this DC-DC converter.

When I measure the output it's showing 6.21 V instead 5.5 V.

I am using [FBMJ2125HM330-T](https://ds.yuden.co.jp/TYCOMPAS/ut/detail?pn=FBMJ2125HM330-T%20%20&u=M) ferrite bead at the output between two 22μF capacitors.

I have attached the circuit diagram I am using currently.

Can someone tell me why I am getting 6.21 V instead of 5.5 V? Is something wrong with my circuit?

[image]

Comment: A minimum load is required (Minimum 10% load is recommended, operation with no load during more than 1s may partially damage the converter output. ). However, what I see in specs is that a capacitor may (must ?) be wired in place of your short, but a "short wire" is not specified ...

Comment: Might be because you've got a very bent and wobbly inductor coil... :-)

Comment: @Antonio51 I am using it as a non-isolated DC-DC converter; I have shorted the input and output grounds of this DC-DC converter.

Comment: @TonyM I tried my best :-)

Comment: "Short wire" not specified, ok ... but not prohibited, so you can try, i think it is ok. But the **Minimum load** is specified, be careful.

Comment: @Antonio51I did power on my 1st assembled board without load.

Comment: Ok ... You were "lucky" ... keep all chances on your side, set a minimum load. :-)

Comment: So I tested board with more than 25% of load and now output voltage reads 5.5V

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're measuring the output voltage with no load, don't do that. The datasheet for this regulator says that the load regulation spec is ±2.5% when the load is between 25% and 100% of rated (450mA - 1.8A), and -2.5% to +20% when the load is less than 25%. 5.5V + 20% = 6.6V, so you're well inside that.

It also says "Minimum 10% load is recommended, operation with no load during more than 1s may partially damage the converter output." so it's *really* not designed for no-load safety.

Comment: I did power on my 1st assembled board without load. They should have mentioned that clause in a bold and bigger size.

Comment: @MightyBeard007   It's like in "contracts" with "insurers"...Always read the clauses in very small letters ...  :-(  Sometimes, I fail ... :-)

Comment: It's a hard way to learn about it, but minimum load requirements are common for regulators of this type.

Comment: @Antonio51 I will keep it in mind

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I have used coupled DC_DC converters, but this is the first one I am seeing about minimum load requirements.

Comment: *always read the fine print*

Comment: That’s lousy behavior for a regulator. If you don’t need isolation there’s lots of good point-of-load choices that will have reasonable no-load regulation.